# Access multidimensional object with dotnotation variable

Tags: javascript

I have a multidimensional object like so:

**Router.js**

```
import Notes from './notes';
import Users from './users';

const router = {
    Notes,
    Users
};

export default router
```

And each of those also have objects like so:

**Notes.js**

```
import Index from '../../components/notes/index'
import Show from '../../components/notes/show'
import Create from '../../components/notes/create'

const routes = {
    index: Index,
    show: Show,
    create: Create
};

export default routes;
```

Now, I am assigning the object to a variable:

**App.js**

```
import Router from 'Router'

var route = Router
var router = function(name) {
    console.log(route[name]) // undefined when using dotnotation
    console.log(route.Notes.create) // works when I manually do it like this
}

router('Notes.create') // I want to access the Notes.create variable
```

So my question is, how can I pass a dotnotation string to my route function to access the 'Notes->create' element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string and get the value by iterating the keys and return the value of the level property.

```
var router = function(name) {
    console.log(name.split('.').reduce((o, k) => o[k], route));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is to not use the notation in this way, but if you insist on it, you can parse the string to get each level of the hierarchy:
Then you can get the properties with bracket notation:

```
function getPropWithDotNotation(obj, selectorString) {
  let hierarchy = selectorString.split('.');
  let result = obj;
  hierarchy.forEach(level => result = result[level]);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic function and check for each keys and take reference

```js
let a = {
  b : {
    c : 'some value'
  }
}

let findBy = (str) => {
  let keys = str.split('.')
  let i=0;
  let op = a;
  while(i < keys.length){
    op = op[keys[i]]
    if(!op) return op
    i++
  }
  return op
}


console.log(findBy('b'))
console.log(findBy('d'))
console.log(findBy('b.c'))
```